# Does Earth rotate around its geometrical axis OR the center of mass of Earth-Moon system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, earth, moon

I just came to know about barycentre. What exactly is this?

Comment: The Earth's rotation is around its own axis+center - it is completely independant of the Earth-moon center. Good question though !

Comment: What is barycentre then ? @Martin

Comment: The earth moon system orbits around the barycenter , ie the center of mass of the pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Earth's spin is about its geometrical axis - that's the *definition* of that axis. This passes through the center of mass (barycenter) of the Earth itself.

Zooming out a bit, the Earth and the Moon both mutually orbit their mutual center of mass (barycenter), which lies inside the Earth but a bit off from its center. This is unrelated, at first brush to the rotation of either body about its own center of mass.

Comment: How does the axis passes through the barycentre ?

Comment: The barycentre of what?

Comment: Refer to the first para of your answer.

Comment: @ZaidAAmir It does, by definition. Unless you have a more precise question, there's nothing else to say.

Comment: I think you mistakenly put "(barycentre)" in the first para. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter

Comment: @ZaidAAmir No. The term barycenter is *always* with respect to some given system, which needs to be specified; thus, the Earth has a barycenter, which does not coincide with the barycenter of the Earth-Moon system. The usages in this answer were carefully qualified; if you do not understand the differences, you need to look more carefully at the language.

Comment: Ok. I thought barycentre to be a binary system property.

Comment: @ZaidAAmir Fair enough; the Wikipedia article is in fact misleading if not wrong. The term barycenter is synonymous with [center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass).

Comment: Any citations ?

Comment: @ZaidAAmir Any introductory textbook, or a suitable dictionary. Happy reading.